# We have a spammer who's copying sentences from pages to "write" fake answers

Tags: discussion, status-completed

This answer copies or rehashes sentences from elsewhere:

> Ancient languages were complex but there is a trend towards simplicity rather complexity. However, numerous languages preserve various remnants of the earliest languages, like the case and gender systems, such as German.
>   — https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/6401/82

Sources:

> ancient languages were complex but there is a trend trend towards simplicity rather complexity.
>   — [Why are many ancient languages so complicated compared to many modern languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6397/why-many-ancient-languages-are-so-complicated-compared-to-many-moderns-one#comment15075_6399)
>
> However, numerous languages preserve various remnants of the earliest languages, like the case and gender systems, such as German.
>   — http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101214002537AARQkgs

It probably uses some kind of bot using computational linguistics. Our own weapons are used against us! On the other hand, the fact that it deleted the double *trend trend* from the first source (a typo) might indicate that the answer was compiled by hand, by a Mechanical Turk (Amazon), perhaps.

Note also that another answer from this user was deleted earlier, as it contained a spam link. Perhaps he uses answers like the above hoping to use reputation to make his spam less easy to identify?

Comment: Another possible explanation is simple plagiarism. Also do you have a link to the deleted answer you mean? The only deleted spam I have run into lately does not link back to the same user.

Comment: @MEd: It is possible, but the spam answer made me think robotic. Is there a way to find deleted answers for a user? I don't know how to find the spam answer.

Comment: @MEd: Ah, here is the spam link: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6400/how-to-make-yourself-more-promising-by-learning-a-new-language

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up, the issue has been solved now.